# Concatenate all gz log files in a directory into a single compressed (gz) file

Tags: windows, command-line, concatenation, gzip, cat

I am trying to concatenate my server log files (gz files named access_log_20191112.gz access_log_20191111.gz etc. ) into one single file (a gz file containing one single file).
Under Windows 10 Powershell command line, I have tried :

> cat access*.gz > Global_File.gz

The command is executed, Global_File.gz has a realistic size as viewed in Explorer, but I can't open it with 7-zip. I get the error : Can not open path/Global_File.gz as archive. I have no problem usually opening gz archives with 7-zip.

Any suggestion to correct this approach or an alternate method to concatenate gz files on a windows 10 machine?

Thx

Comment: On linux, you would need to do`gunzip -c *.log.gz > newBigLog.gz` . This has the advantange that you don't need space to completely unzip a file before you can rezip it into the master file. It will take some time (either way). But you lose knowing specifically which original file a record came from. You'll have to find the powershell equivalent Maybe there is a website that does this sort of translation, or there is an option on https://batsh.org that I haven't noticed. Good luck!

Comment: And, the reason your original approach didn't work is that any `zip` ish file has a header of "words" that it has compressed. You're just jamming all this binary information together into one file, (roughly speaking ), you have a header block followed by it's "data", followed by another header block and its "data" . etc,  (zip enthusiasts, please correct me). For a true zip file you want just one header and one set of "data", so it needs to be "recalculated", hence, the call to `guzip -c` and piping back to `gzip`. Good luck.

Comment: shellter:
Thanks for your detailed answers. I am going to try to use your gunzip instruction via a one line program run server side. Unless someone know how to do that on a windows machine (using command line or an app with GUI).
Cheers!